# Sharing resources/build path between two apps

Tags: android, resources, jar, apk

Here is the issue, i cannot compile all of my jars into one apk, so i have to use two APK'S, if i use one of them as the library, it compile it with no errors, and i can run it(both apk's are installed on the device), but when i use a method that uses some of the jars from the addon apk(the importing of the needed class compiles with no errors), it throw no class found exception, the question then is how should i set the classpath or the manifest file so the dalvik will know that the resouce is avialable on the other apk(which btw is installed on the device too) ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I cant answer your question directly, but I think you should design otherwise, put the bare essentials inside the APK, and place all the large files that are filling up that APK, as files in a separate storage (SD Card most likely). The APK should install, then check for these files, if they are not there, download them.

This is how most big games work.